# How to access to the cells of advancedDatagrid

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder

I was wondering if anyone can help me how I can access to the row data of my advancedDataGrid, I don't have any item Render set , but I do have data provider and dataField set for my grid, I need to check if the grid has been filled with data or not? that is why I need to access to data in the rows, to see if the rows are empty or not?

any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dataprovider is an array of rows, so you only need to make a loop on the dataprovider that will check if the rows are empty or not. For example if you have a datafield "name" in your dataprovider, you could check if it's empty this way:

```
var empty:Boolean=false;
for each (var obj:Object in dataProvider)
{
    if(!obj.name)
        empty=true;
}
```

You could also add another loop to loop on the datafields